# Как расположить элементы в Horizontal Layout Group чтобы они не изменялись по ширине

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-canvas

У меня в unity в канвас есть обьект (типа панель с кнопками) куда я запихнул обьект с Horizontal Layout Group ну и в этот обьект я запихнул кнопки. Так вот количество кнопок постоянно меняется, длина кнопок постоянна а вот ширина кнопок постоянно меняеться, как мне сделать так чтобы ширина кнопок была неизменна? Вот я сейчас кину картинку, потому что так может не понятно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот видите AddictionalPanel содержит Content c Horizontal Layout Group и Content включает кнопки которые включаються и отключаються скриптом в зависимости от необходимости, т.е их стает то больше то меньше и у них соответсвенно меняется ширина, можно что нибудь придумать чтобы их ширина оставалась неизменной ?
Просто если отключить  width в Horizontal Layout Group то тогда кнопки стают узкими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лайфхак...

- На кнопках компанент **Layout Element** с желаемым `Min Width`.
- В начале и конце группы пустые элементы с **Layout Element**, где `Preferred Width` или `Flexible Width` (не помню) что-то типа 9999.
- В настройках группы галочки на `Width` поставить.

В итоге всё лишнее свободное место сьедят пустышки, а кнопки будут желаемой ширины.

Comment: Получилось спасибо большое, но пришлось кроме min width еще добавить Preffered width с таким же параметром как и min width, по другому не выходило